# Calculate angle between 2D vectors in OpenGL (using glm experimental)

Tags: c++, glm-math

I'm trying to do a CPU computation using glm(experimental) for the **angle between two 2D vectors**.

```
#define GLM_ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL
#include <glm/gtx/vector_angle.hpp>
...
glm::vec2 A = glm::vec2(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT - 250);
glm::vec2 B = glm::vec2(30, SCREEN_HEIGHT - 250);
float res = glm::orientedAngle(glm::normalize(A), glm::normalize(B));
```

The result here is: -0.0535194.

**Question #1: Shouldn't the result be π/2 if angle is measured from y-axis or 0 if measured from x-axis??**

Afterwards I use the same code, only changing x coordinate of B vector

```
glm::vec2 A = glm::vec2(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT - 250);
glm::vec2 B = glm::vec2(100, SCREEN_HEIGHT - 250);
float res = glm::orientedAngle(glm::normalize(A), glm::normalize(B));
```

The result here is: -0.176709

**Question #2: Why do I get different angles if I'm "walking" around x-axis in both situations.**

Comment: I don't understand the question.  The returned value is the angle *between* the two vectors specified -- it has nothing to do with the x or y axes.

Comment: Why angle of first code is not equal to angle of second.
Can not explain the question better than that

Comment: Why do you think they should be the same?  `A` is the same in both examples but the `B`s are clearly different: hence the different angles.  Try drawing the vectors on paper and the difference should be obvious.

Comment: Different values for your input vectors will result in a different angle... I think that is totally to be expected.

Comment: May I ask what do you think `A` and `B` are and what *"angle between two 2D vectors"* means? It seems to be a misunderstanding of what `A`, `B` and said angle represent.

Comment: Ok your answers helped a lot. I totally misinterpreted the definition of the angle between two vectors.

I actually needed the direction (angle) from A->B (from y-axis) which can be obtained with:

glm::orientedAngle(glm::normalize(B-A), glm::vec2(0.0f, 1.0f));